# Implementing While loop for part of an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops, while-loop

I have an array x with 10,000 rows and 2 columns. I run a test and then I want the test to repeated until the test will be greater than 7.81 and then stop. Here is the old code.

```
x=matrix(runif(10000*2,0,1),10000,2)
test <- vector(mode="numeric", length=196)
i=0
while(max(test)<7.81 & 200+i*50<=nrow(x))
{
 y = x[seq(1,200+i*50),] # y contains the first 200+i*50 rows of x
 ts= runif(1,1,7.9) # random test statistic, enter yours here.
 test[i]= sum(ts)
 i=i+1}
```

What I am interested to do now is the following:

I would like to run the test until it becomes greater than 7.81 but I want to access my array x in a different way. At a first instance I would like to use only the first 6,000 rows of the array x. Consequently I want to increase the entries of the array by 50. For example 2nd iteration I would like to use the 50th row until 6050, 3rd iter x[100:6100], 4th x[150:6150] and so on.

Comment: what you want is `y <- x[1:6000,]` then `y <- x[50:6050,]` and then `y <- x[100:6100,]` and so on right ?

Comment: Yes right, that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. Note that in order to have 6,000 rows per iteration, you should have rows from 51 to 6,500 in the second iteration, and not 50 to 6,050.

```
x=matrix(runif(10000*2,0,1),10000,2)

test=0
i=0
while(max(test)<7.81 & (6000+i*50)<=nrow(x))
{
  y = x[seq(i*50+1,6000+i*50)] # y contains the first 200+i*50 rows of x
  ts= runif(1,1,7.9) # random test statistic, enter yours here.
  test[i]= sum(ts)
  i=i+1
}
```

You can add this line in the loop to verify:

```
print(paste0(i*50+1," to ", 6000+i*50, ", number of entries: ", 6000+i*50-(i*50+1)+1 ))
```

Output:

```
[1] "1 to 6000, number of entries: 6000"
[1] "51 to 6050, number of entries: 6000"
[1] "101 to 6100, number of entries: 6000"
[1] "151 to 6150, number of entries: 6000"
[1] "201 to 6200, number of entries: 6000"
```

Hope this helps!